# How to increase a version of an npm package using Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-version

The pipeline is triggered by new commits to a `master` branch and publishes the package
Currently, the version is set manually and I'de be happy to have it set automatically.
What I thought at first was adding the following tasks to the pipeline:

1. checkout `$Build.SourceBranch`
2. run `version patch --force`
3. `git push`

This works and the version is really incremented properly, the thing is, it triggers another run of the pipeline, which will increment again, which will.. you get the idea, endless loop.
Is there a better way for doing that?

Comment: The ideal way is to use a build pipeline and a release pipeline. Unfortunately, DevOps makes this hard since the npm command in DevOps wants a path to the full source. Otherwise npm pack in build pipeline could have delivered a nice package you could use with npm publish (It probably is doable but i gave up after lots of tries)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've added the same tasks as mentioned in the question with a small change.
Apparently there is a way to skip the pipeline triggering, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits)

So the `npm version` task looks like this:

```
version patch -m "Bump version to %s [skip ci]" --force
```

which prevents the next build from being triggered.

TIP: remember to give the 'author' (Azure DevOps user) permissions to `Bypass policies when pushing` if any.

Comment: Unless you push that change from the build pipeline back to the origin repo, it will always patch to the same number with every run, right?

Comment: Correct, that has to be pushed, however, that step is a dependency for the `publish` step, so if there is no commit, there'll be no publish :). I can accept it as an answer only in a few hours

Comment: This will only do patch increments... how are you handling minor and major updates?

Comment: @MikeLoffland manually as we have no constant rule for when these should be updated

Comment: The URL is now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits

Answer (score 3):

Here's my implementation in Powershell which is a complete step based on the accepted answer. Note that this also handles some of the git issues such as the detached head that comes with this type of approach.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
.
.
.
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Bump the version'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $BranchName = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace "refs/heads/"
          git checkout $BranchName
          git config --global user.email "anymail@anycompany.com"
          git config --global user.name "Your name"
          npm version prerelease -m "Auto increment pre-release version to %s [skip ci]" --force
          git push
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the files in the source repo to keep track of the current/next version. I don't think you can break the loop easily, if you do.

You might be able to get away with running `npm --no-git-tag-version version` to increment the package.json version inside the build agent without the commit, so that you don't have a change you would have to push back to the origin. It should just change package.json and leave it dirty.

Wait until after the build has succeeded. Use a custom script task to extract the version from package.json, then `git reset --hard` (there is no reason to keep anything that has changed on the build server). While this will undo the change in package.json, you can now create a tag on the head that contains that version, then do a `git push origin {tag-name}` which should not introduce a new commit on the origin which would then re-trigger your pipeline.

Actually, I don't *think* a pipeline will be triggered just because a tag was added, but I honestly haven't tested it. I'm pretty sure it won't.

Sequence of tasks in your pipeline:

[Given a source repo where you have made sure to set the major and minor versions in package.json to reflect the current state of the code according to the rules of Semantic Versioning, and leave the patch value always set to 0, and, if desired, using pre-* values to describe the quality of the major/minor value:]

1. (This is not really a task, but just describing the start of the execution:) The job starts. Automatically, the code is pulled from the source repo into the build agent.
2. Using a utility command-line task and code or script that you write, run `git describe --tags` to find the most recent tag with a *tagname* matching the pattern you use (see below). (I prefer this sequence over calling `npm version from-git` because npm will just use the latest tag, which might not be a version number, depending on how much control you have over the branch.) Use string or regular expression operations to extract the major, minor, patch, and whatever pre-* value you might have. This is the previous version that we'll use to compare with what's in the package.json file. Note that you may have to follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run a git command. [Save it to a pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script).
3. Using a utility command-line task and code or script that you write, run `npm version` to get the current major/minor/pre version out of the package.json file and save it to a different pipeline variable. I'm using PowerShell Core, so my command would look something like this to create a "currentPackageVersion" pipeline variable:

   ```
   & npm.cmd version | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty {name-of-your-package} | Set-Variable -Name 'packageVersion' | Write-Output "#vso[task.setvariable variable=currentPackageVersion]$packageVersion"
   ```
4. Using a utility command-line task and code or script that you write, compare the previous version's major, minor, and pre-* values to determine whether any of them have changed. Set a new pipeline variable to reflect whether it has changed or not. I'll use the name "restartVersionPatchNumber", which is true if the current major, minor, or pre-* values are different from the previous version's major, minor, or pre-* values.
5. The npm Task ***conditionally*** runs a custom command: `npm --no-git-tag-version version patch`, which updates package.json in the build agent but does not commit the change, leaving your Working Area modified (dirty) (which might cause issues on subsequent builds if you are using your own build agents instead of hosted agents). The [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-control-options) expression of the Task uses a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that [evaluates to the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables) that I just set in the previous step ("restartVersionPatchNumber"). Note that if this task does not run, it should just use the value of the version that is in the package.json file (the current version that is now in the "currentPackageVersion" pipeline variable).
6. Using a utility command-line task and code or script that you write, run `npm version` to extract the new version that the npm version command set. Save it to a new pipeline variable; I'll call it "newVersionNumber".
7. The regular build tasks run, producing artifacts and possibly publishing them
8. Using a utility command-line task, run `git reset --hard`. You'll need to do this even if you're using a hosted build agent, because of the next step.
9. Using a utility command-line task, create a variable from the saved version number ("newVersionNumber") that contains the value of the tag's *tagname* that you want to use. Use a distinctive patter, like "AzPipelineBuild-PipelineName-PackageVersion-1.0.0" but using your version instead of 1.0.0.
10. Using a utility command-line task, run `git tag {*tagname*}`. For PowerShell, the syntax would be `& git.exe tag $env:newVersionNumber`
11. Using a utility command-line task, run `git push origin {*tagname*}`
12. Profit

You could (and maybe should) combine the command-line steps. I'm really partial to the PowerShell task running PowerShellCore (pwsh) as you may have guessed.

The package that got created as an artifact of the job will have the updated version as it was created in the build, and it will match the tag that is now in your original source code repo.

---

Alternately, use an external source (an Azure Function, etc.) or a different (second) git repo or even another branch that isn't tied to your CI trigger in your project that you use just for tracking build numbers, then use token replacement tasks to set the version just before you start the build. I don't like this idea much, but it would prevent re-triggering a new build.

---

Also, you're hopefully building just one package with that repo. The next thing to do is to publish that package to your Azure Artifacts feed, or npmjs.org or wherever. Don't rely on having the version baked into the original source code; anything that depends on that package should be pulling it out of that feed you published it to, not relying on it being built earlier in the build steps with a new version number.

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm not really sure I understand, the version must exist in the `package.json` file, otherwise, users won't be able to update. git tags are nice but it's only relevant for self-monitoring. The simplest way I could think of (if possible) is to exclude the DevOps user commits from triggering the pipeline, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: @SagiLow I have heavily edited my answer. LMK if that helps

Comment: Thank you, we are not really working with tags and IMHO it will make it hard to keep up with the versions. Also, it means the `package.json` version is never correct and that's confusing. I think I've found a simpler solution to my issue, please see my answer below. Thank you very much for your answer!